# Can I store start time, end time & duration of a process in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

My question is, is it possible to store start time, end time & duration of a process in prometheus TSDB?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Prometheus can scrape metrics that represent the start/end time of a process (and the duration) but since the service is responsible for exposing the metrics, exposing a end time is tricky. The only use cas your question make sense is the case of batch processes which is kind of a corner case.